# Python Dataframe apply causing error "List index out of range"

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that contains a bunch of urls to PDF files. I want to extract the filenames into a separate column. I tried it on a MWE and it works but my main dataset is giving me this error. Can someone please help me understand what the source of the error might be

MWE

```
my_dict = {"url": ["http://www.someting.com/file/file1.pdf", "http://www.someting.com/file/file37.pdf"]}
my_test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)

def get_filename_from_url(url):

    #Commenting out a bunch of stuff because my final goal is to do NLP on the extracted text        
    #response = requests.get(url)
    #my_raw_data = response.content

    m = re.search('[^/]+$', url)
    if m is None:
        return None
   
    file_name = m.group(0)

    return file_name

my_test_df['File_name'] = my_test_df.apply(lambda row: get_filename_from_url(row['url']),axis=1)
```

This works, and my DF looks like what I expected it to.

[image]

But for my actual dataframe,

[image]

when I do this, it works:

[image]

But when I try apply to create a new column, I get an error.

```
my_main_df['File_name3'] = my_main_df.apply(lambda row: get_filename_from_url(row['PDF Links']),axis=1)
```

I get the following error. I don't understand which list's index is getting messed up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-dd127df2eb83> in <module>
----> 1 my_main_df['File_name3'] = my_main_df.apply(lambda row: get_filename_from_url(row['PDF Links']),axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3161         else:
   3162             # set column
-> 3163             self._set_item(key, value)
   3164 
   3165     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3244         # value exception to occur first
   3245         if len(self):
-> 3246             self._check_setitem_copy()
   3247 
   3248     def _set_value(self, index, col, value, takeable: bool = False):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _check_setitem_copy(self, stacklevel, t, force)
   3935             raise com.SettingWithCopyError(t)
   3936         elif value == "warn":
-> 3937             warnings.warn(t, com.SettingWithCopyWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
   3938 
   3939     def __delitem__(self, key) -> None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\warnings.py in _showwarnmsg(msg)
    107                                 "function or method")
    108 
--> 109             sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
    110                msg.file, msg.line)
    111             return

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in _showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line)
   1067                     file = sys.stderr
   1068                 try:
-> 1069                     file.write(formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
   1070                 except IOError:
   1071                     pass

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py in formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line)
     67 #custom implementation of warnings.formatwarning
     68 def formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
---> 69     file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name
     70     return "%s: %s [%s:%s]\n" % (category.__name__, message, file, lineno)
     71 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Update:

When I use "head" to essentially extract all the rows of my main dataframe, the apply command works. Note that my main df only has 386 rows so head(400) basically catches all rows.

[image]

Commands in the screenshot above, copied here. I am so confused.

```
df2 = my_main_df.head(400)
df2['File_name_test'] = df2.apply(lambda row: get_filename_from_url(row['PDF Links']),axis=1)
```

Comment: try, ``my_test_df['url'].str.split("/").str[-1]`` ?

Comment: @sushanth Thanks. Two questions. 1. How can I save that output to create a new column? What I am doing with apply to my_main_df.apply(lambda x : my_fuc(x)) also works but how do I save it to a new column? 2. Why is what I am doing causing an error for my main DF but not MWE?

Comment: First question: Just go `my_test_df['column_name'] = my_test_df['url'].str.split("/").str[-1]`. That creates a new column in pandas. The second question I don't understand.